# Can i staple multiple feature in moss 2007

Tags: feature-stapling

I have deployed a Feature Stapler feature that attach two feature to the BLANKINTERNET#2 template. Now I need to update this staple feature to add one more feature. I have already added another feature association in elements.xml file but it's not working meaning only the first two features gets, not the one I just added.
Here are the current contents of the elements.xml file:

```
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="1748e53b-e130-4e9a-9696-510711449809" 
    TemplateName="BLANKINTERNET#2">
</FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="1748e53b-e130-4e9a-9696-510711449809" 
    TemplateName="BLANKINTERNET#0">
</FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="209ac08d-d4de-47e9-b61d-30341ec6266c" 
    TemplateName="BLANKINTERNET#2">
</FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="209ac08d-d4de-47e9-b61d-30341ec6266c" 
    TemplateName="BLANKINTERNET#0">
</FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>
```

Please advise.

Thanks 
Ronak

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem in stapling multiple feature. If you look at:

> SharePointRoot\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\BaseSiteStapling\basesitestapling.xml

In that Microsoft is stapling 4 features to a lot of templates.

Remember that you can't assume on anything about the order of the activation of these feature and that they'll activate before any `<ListInstance>s` and `<Module>s` in the site definition

Comment: Thanks Per that what i thought too but its not working after updating elements.xml file and then i did full deployment again.

Comment: Did you deactivate/activate the feature?

Comment: yes i did deactivate staple feature which will activated other features and then redeploy solution.